# Sublime Text 2: How to make Sublime run a command (fold code) when opening a file by default?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I would like to make it so that whenever I open a file in Sublime it will automatically do "Fold Level 2" Coding which is command shortcut Ctrl-K,Ctrl-2 (or CMD-K, CMD-2). I use both mac and pc.

I don't want to enter that shortcut everytime, instead I would like Sublime to automatically run that on opening a file. Please let me know if there a way to do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that the best solution to your problem is [Buffer Scroll](https://github.com/SublimeText/BufferScroll) plugin. It remembers and restores a lot of things, folding included.

If you don't want to install that plugin, you can create your own:

1. Create new plugin `Tools / New Plugin...`
2. Insert code

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class Folding(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        view.run_command("fold_by_level", {"level": 2})
```

1. Save it in your `User` directory with the filename you prefer.

This will set folding level to 2, for every file you open.

Comment: this is not exactly the answer though - this will only remember state on files that have been opened before. I believe Risha is looking for a default setting for code folding level.  I am also, thus I found this question.

Comment: I should have read more before commenting - the code snippet given definitely does the default setting, though awkward (would be better to be a regular User setting for sublime itself)